# XML format in Python

Tags: python, xml

I needed to take an XML file and replace certain values with other values.
This was easy enough parsing through the xml (as text) and replacing the old values with the new.
The issue is the new txt file is in the wrong format.
It's all encased in square brackets and has "/n" characters instead of linebreaks.

I did try the xml.dom.minidom lib but it's not working ...

I could parse the resulting file aswell and remove the "/n" and square brackets but don't want to do that as I am not sure this is the only thing that has been added in this format.
source code :

```
import json
import shutil
import itertools
import datetime
import time
import calendar
import sys
import string
import random
import uuid
import xml.dom.minidom

inputfile = open('data.txt')
outputfile = open('output.xml','w')

sess_id = "d87c2b8e063e5e5c789d277c34ea"
new_sess_id = ""
number_of_sessions = 4

my_text =  str(inputfile.readlines())
my_text2 = ''
#print (my_text)

#Just replicate the session logs x times ... 

#print ("UUID random : " + str(uuid.uuid4()).replace("-","")[0:28])

for i in range (0,number_of_sessions):
     new_sess_id = str(uuid.uuid4()).replace("-","")[0:28]
     my_text2 = my_text + my_text2
     my_text2 = my_text2.replace(sess_id,new_sess_id)



#xml = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(my_text2)

outputfile.write(my_text2)

print (my_text)

inputfile.close()
outputfile.close()
```

The original text is XML format but the output is like

```
time is it&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div 
class=\\"di_transcriptAvatarAnswerEntry\\"&gt;&lt;span 
class=\\"di_transcriptAvatarTitle\\"&gt;[AVATAR] &lt;/span&gt; &lt;span 
class=\\"di_transcriptAvatarAnswerText\\"&gt;My watch says it\'s 6:07 
PM.&lt;br/&gt;Was my answer helpful? No Yes&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;\\r\\n"
</variable>\n', '</element>\n', '</path>\n', '</transaction>\n', 
'</session>\n', '<session>']
```

Comment: Please add more explanation and example code. What you had, what you get and what you did.

Comment: use `outputfile.writelines`

Comment: Try changing `my_text =  str(inputfile.readlines())` to `my_text = inputfile.read()`. Currently you are creating a list of lines and converting it to a string (complete with brackets and quotes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently using `readlines()`. This will read each line of your file and return you a Python list, one line per entry (complete with \n on the end of each entry). You were then using `str()` to convert the list representation into a string, for example:

```
text = str(['line1\n', 'line2\n', line3\n'])
```

`text` would now be a string looking like a your list, complete with all the `[` and quote characters. Rather than using `readlines()`, you probably need to just use `read()` which would return the whole file contents as a single text string for you to work with.

Try using the following type approach which also uses the preferred `with` context manager for dealing with files (it closes them automatically for you).

```
import uuid

sess_id = "d87c2b8e063e5e5c789d277c34ea"
new_sess_id = ""
number_of_sessions = 4

with open('data.txt') as inputfile, open('output.xml','w') as outputfile:
    my_text =  inputfile.read()
    my_text2 = ''

    #Just replicate the session logs x times ... 

    for i in range (0,number_of_sessions):
         new_sess_id = str(uuid.uuid4()).replace("-","")[0:28]
         my_text2 = my_text + my_text2
         my_text2 = my_text2.replace(sess_id,new_sess_id)

    outputfile.write(my_text2)
```

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help! Don't forget to accept the answer.